# Click on random Google Search result using NodeJS and Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm attempting on making a small script to click on a random Google Search result after searching "'what is ' + Word." Nothing I've done has been able to get me the results I want, heck, I can't even get the script to click a single Google Search result!

I've tried doing multiple things here, such as collecting all search results in an array and clicking a random one (didn't collect into an array), clicking an element by partial text (https:// brought no results), and many other solutions that work in Python, but don't work here.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const searchbar = "#tsf > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.RNNXgb > div >   div.a4bIc > input"



async function gsearch() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, args:['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://google.com');
 var fs  = require("fs");
var array = fs.readFileSync("words.txt").toString().split('\n');
var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
await page.click(searchbar)
await page.keyboard.type("what is " + random);
await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.evaluate(() => {
  let elements = $('LC20lb').toArray();
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    $(elements[i]).click();


  } 
 })
}

gsearch();
```

(ignore any indent-inheritant errors, I swear it looks cleaner in VSC)

Expected to click a random search result. End up getting nothing done, maybe an error or two but that's about it.

Comment: It's just some UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LC20lb` is not html tag and it should be class name for `h3` and by using`$()`  are you trying to select elements with jQuery? use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require("fs");

async function gsearch() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://google.com');
  var array = fs.readFileSync("words.txt").toString().split('\n');
  var random = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  // simple selector for search box
  await page.click('[name=q]');
  await page.keyboard.type("what is " + random);
  // you forgot this
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  // wait for search results
  await page.waitForSelector('h3.LC20lb', {timeout: 10000});
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('h3.LC20lb')
    // "for loop" will click all element not random
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length) + 1
    elements[randomIndex].click();
  })
}
```

Comment: Should be `Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length)` or the first element will never get clicked.